# How do you zoom out?

Tags: dota-2

Is there any way to zoom out the camera in DotA 2?  I've found my ideal aspect ratio - and holy crap, is the resolution terrible if you're not on the right one!

Even with the right ratio, I feel like I can't quite see enough of the screen, especially in the vertical direction.  Any tips?

Comment: Just letting you know I edited the game titles out of your question titles because we prefer that they are left out unless they're asked in an organic matter (like "How do you hzoom out in DotA 2?" rather than using "DotA 2:/DotA 2-<insert question>). The question's tag contains the game title and should usually serve that purpose in most cases.

Comment: I'm not going to try to disagree with the proverbial "we" here, but man, that title just sounds awful now.

Comment: Could you expand on that Norla? I think the title is fine, and I agree with @FallenAngelEyes earlier comment.

Comment: I can expand a bit, as zoom in/out is so common across games this makes sense for it to be in the title, organically ofcourse.

Comment: Different perspective, consider your utilization of the mini map and whether that can be improved...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way to zoom out further. You can zoom in, that's all.

Comment: While I appreciate the answer, I'd like to hear your argument on why zooming out would be cheating.  If everyone can do it...

Comment: @Norla certain characters benefit more from a larger view than others, I think its more of a balance thing.

Comment: There is a fog of war applied, zooming out really wouldn't be advantageous anyway.

Comment: @Emerica. (friendly debate) I disagree.  Often times I like to click to walk outside of the fog range.  I was the QOP yesterday, trying to blink in and out of the river.  With a 1000+ range, you can't even see your hero when you're looking for a place to blink to.

Comment: I play LoL and not Dota these days but damn that blinks got range then haha.

Comment: What if you were blind everytime you moved ten feet and couldn't run further until you pressed some keys... that's DOTA

Answer (score 3):

You can't zoom out during normal game play, but you can [unlock the camera](http://www.cyborgmatt.com/2012/02/dota-2-tips-for-movie-makers/) while viewing replays.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to zoom out further, I am sorry.

Because of this I strongly recommend moving the keys that direct the camera to a very easy to get spot, and get used to using them exclusively... in fact, turn off edge-panning, and increase the camera pan speed a lot. This will improve your ability to look around frequently during gameplay, despite having a limited field of view.

I should note that widescreen displays see a larger portion of the gamefield than narrow ones; they see more to the sides. Because of this, attacking from above or below is often more effective than from a side, as the vertical view is fixed and limited, but the horizontal is much greater.

Comment: any proof to that? i doubt that they would give widescreenusers such an advantage. normally 4:3 screen gets the same view.

Comment: Try it yourself. It's not hard to test. Change your screen resolution and measure how far you can see up and down, and left/right. Set an aspect that is off for your screen, and you can test it (even if it's distorted).

Answer (score -3):

dota_camera_distance 1700

gghg