# How do you zoom out when watching a replay?

Tags: dota-2

**Can you zoom out while watching a replay?**

I know my question [has been asked for *playing* the game](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/49473/11084) and I understand that [you can't](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/49477/11084). In [another answer to that question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/49482/11084) it's claimed that:

> ...but you can [unlock the camera](http://www.cyborgmatt.com/2012/02/dota-2-tips-for-movie-makers/) while viewing replays.

However, linked article is from 2012, and involves a lot of console commands, whereas you often see casters zoom out on a whim. I think I started seeing that in 2013 or later, so it feels like a proper feature had been introduced to do so. [A Steam Forum thread](http://steamcommunity.com/app/570/discussions/0/43099721298318794/) suggests the same (emphasis mine):

> **Question:**
>   i was watching Ti4 playoffs and dota 2 casters zoomed out game from very high point of view how can i do that ingame ? i want to zoomout far
>
> **Reply:**
>   **Sure you can**, you just need to spectate (or watch replays) **in free camera mode and use the mousewheel to zoom in and out**. I often do that when a teamfight is about to break out, I switch to free camera mode and zoom out a little...

However, I've tried this while watching one of my own replays, and it doesn't seem to work. What am I missing here?

Things I've tried:

- Changing the camera mode to all different options;
- Going through all of the Spectator key bindings;
- Meticulously go through all replay UI components to find an option for this;
- Double checking my scroll wheel is still working :D
- Searching with [Google (last year's results)](https://www.google.nl/search?q=dota%202%20zoom%20out%20replay#q=dota%202%20zoom%20out%20replay&tbs=qdr:y) as well as [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bdota-2%5D%20zoom%20out%20is%3Aq);

No dice.

What are the current instructions for zooming out while watching a replay?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has indeed been possible for quite some time now. Perhaps you've been following the [advice on disabling zooming](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/169353/11084)? Because however nice that may be for normal gameplay, it also prevents you from zooming out during replays.

Look in this folder / file:

```
\Steam\SteamApps\common\dota 2 beta\dota\cfg\autoexec.cfg
```

And check if it has the following:

```
dota_camera_disable_zoom "1"
```

It should be set to `"0"` if you want to be able to zoom out. Here's a screenshot of how wide a field of view you can get while zoomed out during a replay:

[image: zoomed out view of mid]

Answer (score -2):

You can use your mouse wheel to zoom out while watching replay.

Comment: I mentioned trying this in my question, as well as the fact that it didn't in this scenario (in fact, that actually *was* the problem).